# Controlling the display format of a rss feed

Tags: 6, feeds

I am using drupal 6. I have created an RSS feed to display the nodes of a certain type (set in the filter). This type of content has many different fields, but I only want to display some of them. Is this possible? At the moment I am very new to Drupal, and I am only working in the front end view.

To fix this issue, do I need to go deeper and mess with the PHP code somewhere?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/views_rss

Comment: @yitznewton: can you make that an answer? I'd almost submitted the same when I saw your comment.

Comment: I did make it an answer on SO :( will do again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the module [Views RSS](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss)